# Does every $\sigma$-algebra contain a countable `disjoint' basis?

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$.

Does there always exist a countable partition of $\Omega$ denoted $\{A_i\}$ s.t. (i) $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ (ii) $A_i$'s are disjoint wrt each other, (iii) $\sqcup_i A_i = \Omega$ and (iv) Any $F \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow F$ can be written as the countable union of elements from $\{A_i\}$?

(Here if you view $\mathcal{F}$ as a topology over $\Omega$, then essentially $\{ A_i\}$ is a countable `disjoint' basis of $\mathcal{F}$ contained in $\mathcal{F}$.)

**Motivation for Problem**. Let $X$ be a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable rv, then $E[X | \mathcal{F}]$ is defined using an existential definition (i.e. $E[X | \mathcal{F}]$ is a random variable which satisfies ... , and it's existence is guaranteed if $E[|X|] < \infty$). But if we have the above mentioned countable `disjoint' basis for $\mathcal{F}$ then we can write an explicit summation for $E[X | \mathcal{F}]$ to reason about some properties. My question just asks if I can always write such a summation for $E[X | \mathcal{F}]$.

Comment: Though we use ` and ' for quotes in $\LaTeX$, it's okay to use normal "smart" single and double quotation marks on this and most sites, which will render them appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal B$ on $\Bbb R$ is a counterexample. If there were such a partition and $x<y$ were distinct element of $A_i$ then every measurable set would contain either both $x$ and $y$ or neither $x$ nor $y$. No such pairs of elements exist for $\mathcal B$: in particular $\bigl(-\infty, \frac{x+y}2\bigr) $ contains only $x$.

Thus any such partition giving $\mathcal B$ would have to be the decomposition into singletons, hence uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

The power set of $\mathbb R$ is an easy counter-example: Every singleton set would be a union of some of the $A_i$s which means that every singleton set is one of the $A_i$'s making the collection $(A_i)$ uncountable. .